# wordpress register form to salesforce

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a saleforce form for registering users on wordpress so that when a user registers on the frontend their details are sent to saleforce CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would vary depending on what form tool, if any, you're using, but lately I've been using Gravity Forms and have had great success with connecting to Salesforce via a custom Gravity forms redirect confirmation.

Once you have a form built in Gravity Forms, go to Form Settings > Confirmations. Edit the default Confirmation and change to Type "Redirect". You'll want to post the form to Salesforce's Web-To-Lead API, so enter `https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead` in the Redirect URL field.

You'll then pass the fields you need via a query string, so check the 'Pass Field Data Via Query String' box, then configure the query string with Salesforce field names and Gravity forms merge tags. There are a couple required parameters including the encoding, your Salesforce Company ID, and a return URL to redirect back to after the form is submitted.

Leave off the `?` to begin the query string, so it looks like

`encoding=UTF-8&oid=0123456789&retURL=http://example.com`

then add fields such as first name, last name, company, country, etc. by adding a parameter for each and selecting the appropriate Gravity Form merge tag from the menu on the right. It will end up looking something like

`&first_name={First Name:1}&last_name={Last Name:2}&company={Company:3}`

You can also send data to custom fields in Salesforce if you find the field ID. The easiest way to do this is by creating a Web-to-lead form in Salesforce and copying the field's name.

All together, your confirmation should look something like this -

[image: GF confirmation]

For bonus points, you could add a hidden field to the form for the Return URL and populate it dynamically on the page, either by pulling the current page URL, or adding a custom field to choose a Return URL dynamically.

If you're not using Gravity Forms, you can still use Salesforce's Web-To-Lead tool by creating your own form, or using theirs, and sending the data in a query string.

Comment: This is so simple, but it's working as expected. Read more about how to obtain OID hidden field from Salesforce interface, and you are good to go, without any extra plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There are various plugins that allow you to send data to Salesforce from a form, such as [WordPress-to-lead for Salesforce CRM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/).

It is also possible to use the Salesforce API to build a single signon, and register users to or from either service. I built one for SugarCRM, which you can view the code for it at [Github](https://github.com/fostertime/SugarCRM-WordPress-Authentication) to get an idea of how it might work with Salesforce.